# HBase Data only in Key + compound key & wildcards

Tags: hbase

Here are my questions:

1) Have you tried to put all the data only in the rowkey? I have really small rows (but millions of them) of data and need to combine more of the data entities together to make the key unique, so my the idea was to create a compound key using all the stuff I need to store in HBase. Have you tried it, what do you think might be the bottleneck/problem? What should be taken into consideration? I can imagine that this would need more RAM since I will have more stuff to put into the bloom filters.

2) I just want a confirmation for this, because I could not find it in this form. As far as I get HBase, if I have a compound key, lets say:
key: k1_k2_x

I could do a range scan to  get all k2 entries for a particular k1, for ex.: 
scan "t1",{STARTROW=>"k1_"}

but there is no way to use a wildcard and somehow get all k1 entries for a particular k2. I would need a map/reduce job or Hive or a filter for this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Its perfectly fine to put all your data in the row-key. HBase is designed to support use cases like this.

2) If you want to do range scans (or "wildcard scans") on both k1 and k2 I recommend storing the data in two tables like this:

- table1: k1_k2_x
- table2: k2_k1_x

This is duplicate data, but will be very efficient for doing the sort of queries you want.

This is one of the tradeoffs with HBase: you get really large scaling capabilities, but lose RDBMS features, and need to work out efficient ways of inserting/querying through your row-key structure.

Comment: Thanks Suman, about 2) I was considered doing this, but in my case, the data put in HBase takes two to tree times more disk space as in HDFS, so I not sure I can afford doing this. But thanks, your response ensures me that I was thinking the right way.